# How to use RxSwift to implement whether a view is hidden by a button's click state (isSelected)

Tags: ios

I want to have the view hidden when the button is selected and the view shown when button is deselected, how do I do it using RxSwift?

Comment: what do u mean by button is selected/unselected? do u mean `UIControlState.Normal` state and `UIControlState.Selected` state?

Comment: It's quite tricky, at least for me. See my answer.

Comment: the `isSelected` property @SandeepBhandari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I created a custom control, a checkbox out of `UIButton`, I actually struggled observing that `isSelected` property. But here's an easy way:

1. Subclass the `UIButton` (this is optional, but in this way, you get shorter lines in your controller).
2. In your custom button, subscribe to its own `.rx.tap`.
3. Have a `BehaviorRelay` called `isSelectedBinder` in your button.
4. Finally, you can now bind that `isSelectedBinder` of your instantiated button to the `.rx.isHidden` of your whatever view.

**Controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: MyButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var someView: UIView!

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.button.isSelectedBinder
            .bind(to: self.someView.rx.isHidden)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

**Button**

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    var isSelectedBinder = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: true)
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        weak var weakSelf = self

        self.rx.tap.subscribe { _ in
            print("TAP")
            guard let strongSelf = weakSelf else { return }
            strongSelf.isSelectedBinder.accept(!strongSelf.isSelectedBinder.value)
            }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.You`ve been very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to mark an answer as the answer to your question if it actually answered your query. :)

Comment: Sorry, i forgot it. is it OK now ? @Glenn

Comment: Yep. You can also change your selected answer in the future for your other questions, just so you know. Welcome to Stackoverflow btw.